# MERGE statement produces multiple "Invalid column name"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, merge

I'm trying to use the MERGE statement in the following procedure:

```
BEGIN

    MERGE INTO dm_udm.D_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY AS DIM
    USING (SELECT ID AS ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY
            ,AnomalyType
            ,AnomalyCategoryID
            ,AnomalyTypeDesc
        FROM src_udm.AnomalyTypesCategory
    )AS STG (
             ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY
            ,DES_ANOMALY_TYPE
            ,ID_ANOMALY_CATEGORY
            ,DES_ANOMALY_TYPE_DESC
            )
    ON DIM.ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY=STG.ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN UPDATE SET                     
        DIM.ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY           =   STG.ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY
        ,DIM.DES_ANOMALY_TYPE                   =   STG.AnomalyType
        ,DIM.ID_ANOMALY_CATEGORY                =   STG.AnomalyCategoryID
        ,DIM.DES_ANOMALY_TYPE_DESC              =   STG.AnomalyTypeDesc
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT
        (
            ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY   
            ,DES_ANOMALY_TYPE           
            ,ID_ANOMALY_CATEGORY            
            ,DES_ANOMALY_TYPE_DESC      
        )
    VALUES
        (
            STG.ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY
            ,STG.AnomalyType
            ,STG.AnomalyCategoryID
            ,STG.AnomalyTypeDesc
        );
END
```

But I'm receiving the following error after the procedure execution:

```
Invalid column name 'AnomalyCategoryID'.
Invalid column name 'AnomalyCategoryID'.
Invalid column name 'AnomalyTypeDesc'.
Invalid column name 'AnomalyTypeDesc'.
Invalid column name 'AnomalyType'.
Invalid column name 'AnomalyType'.
```

It seems that all aliases are correct and I don't understand why I get this errors.

Any ideas on how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please try to remove this part (
             ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY
            ,DES_ANOMALY_TYPE
            ,ID_ANOMALY_CATEGORY
            ,DES_ANOMALY_TYPE_DESC
            )

Comment: `AS STG` is followed by aliases, then you don't use the aliases. So remove them

Comment: These were the issues, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using Aliases after AS STG, try the following :

```
BEGIN

    MERGE INTO dm_udm.D_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY AS DIM
    USING (SELECT ID AS ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY
            ,AnomalyType
            ,AnomalyCategoryID
            ,AnomalyTypeDesc
        FROM src_udm.AnomalyTypesCategory
    )AS STG 
    ON DIM.ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY=STG.ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN UPDATE SET                     
        DIM.ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY           =   STG.ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY
        ,DIM.DES_ANOMALY_TYPE                   =   STG.AnomalyType
        ,DIM.ID_ANOMALY_CATEGORY                =   STG.AnomalyCategoryID
        ,DIM.DES_ANOMALY_TYPE_DESC              =   STG.AnomalyTypeDesc
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT
        (
            ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY   
            ,DES_ANOMALY_TYPE           
            ,ID_ANOMALY_CATEGORY            
            ,DES_ANOMALY_TYPE_DESC      
        )
    VALUES
        (
            STG.ID_ANOMALY_TYPES_CATEGORY
            ,STG.AnomalyType
            ,STG.AnomalyCategoryID
            ,STG.AnomalyTypeDesc
        );
END
```